# Complex jq Filter

Tags: json, jq

***Disclaimer:  this is not homework, this is a sanitized version of something I'm doing for work.***

I'm trying to filter some json data using jq and want to return an object for each matching record in my filter.  Here's a text description of what I'm doing: "Given a JSON object containing a list of students, some personal info, and their grades, return a list of the name, ages, and cumulative gpa for each student that received an A in CSC101."

Here's the test JSON object (program input):

```
{
    "students": [
        {"name": "John", "age": "19", "gender": "m", "from": "Tampa, FL", "cum_gpa": "3.83", "semesters": [
            {"name": "201302", "gpa": "3.67", "grades": {"CSC101": "A", "MAT101": "A", "PSY101": "B"}},
            {"name": "201401", "gpa": "4.00", "grades": {"CSC201": "A", "MAT201": "A", "HIS101": "A"}}
        ]},
        {"name": "Mary", "age": "20", "gender": "f", "from": "Chicago, IL", "cum_gpa": "3.50", "semesters": [
            {"name": "201302", "gpa": "4.00", "grades": {"CSC101": "A", "MAT101": "A", "ECO101": "A"}},
            {"name": "201401", "gpa": "3.00", "grades": {"CSC201": "B", "MAT201": "B", "HUM101": "B"}}
        ]},
        {"name": "Dan", "age": "20", "gender": "m", "from": "Seattle, WA", "cum_gpa": "3.33", "semesters": [
            {"name": "201302", "gpa": "3.33", "grades": {"CHE101": "B", "MAT101": "A", "PSY101": "B"}},
            {"name": "201401", "gpa": "3.33", "grades": {"CHE201": "A", "MAT201": "A", "HUM101": "C"}}
        ]}
    ]
}
```

Here's my current filter expression and the result:

```
cat test.json |jq -c '.students[]|select(.semesters[].grades.CSC101 == "A")|{name: .name, age: .age, gpa: .cum_gpa, CSC101: .semesters[].grades.CSC101}' 
{"name":"John","age":"19","gpa":"3.83","CSC101":"A"}
{"name":"John","age":"19","gpa":"3.83","CSC101":null}
{"name":"Mary","age":"20","gpa":"3.50","CSC101":"A"}
{"name":"Mary","age":"20","gpa":"3.50","CSC101":null}
```

It's sort-of working, but it generates extra output.  I only want it to yield the semesters that have an entry for CSC101, but instead it returns all semesters for any student that took CSC101. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this filter:

```
.students | map(
    {
        name,
        age,
        gpa: .cum_gpa,
        CSC101: .semesters | map(.grades) | add | .CSC101
    }
    |
    select(.CSC101 == "A")
)
```

The idea is to merge all grades from all semesters for each student and grab the `CSC101` grade.  Then filter the students out that have an A grade.

This results in:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "19",
    "gpa": "3.83",
    "CSC101": "A"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary",
    "age": "20",
    "gpa": "3.50",
    "CSC101": "A"
  }
]
```

Comment: Trying this on jqplay.org, getting "error: syntax error, unexpected QQSTRING_START"

Comment: Check the inputs. I wrote this up on jqplay.org and was able to get the result. It's too bad we can't link to a specific result there.

Comment: Not sure if the single-line version of the filter is the issue, as your example above is multi-line.  Here's what I copied:  .students | map( {name, age, gpa: .cum_gpa, CSC101: .semesters|map(.grades)|add|.CSC101 }) | map(select(.CSC101 == A"))

Comment: Oh you could always remove the newlines and make it single line. I only split it into multiple lines for readability here. Try my revised version (I removed the extra map): `.students | map({ name, age, gpa: .cum_gpa, CSC101: .semesters | map(.grades) | add | .CSC101 } | select(.CSC101 == "A"))`

Comment: BTW, I see the problem you had when you copied the original filter. You missed the quote around the `A` at the end. The error must have been referring to the unbalanced quotes.